# OpenGL ES texture cut from it

Tags: opengl-es

I have a big texture, 256*256 there is 64*64 pixel textures on it. How I can cut it, and use as a texture?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you mean cut it up in advance? Or do you want a "texture atlas" where you access sub-rectangles on it when you're texture mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just draw with the correct texture coordinates, for example, to draw a quad from (0,0) to (64,64) from the texture, use texture coords (0,0) to (64 / 256.0, 64 / 256.0)